# last number in array negative instead of positive

Tags: c

i use

```
(unsigned int*)malloc((n) * (sizeof(unsigned int))+1)
```

to create the array,The results I get:

```
1
2
4
8
16
32
64
128
256
512
1024
2048
4096
8192
16384
32768
65536
131072
262144
524288
1048576
2097152
4194304
8388608
16777216
33554432
67108864
134217728
268435456
536870912
1073741824
-2147483648
```

the result is **fine and accurate**,
But why do I get minus at the end?
it should be 2147483648 only
Thank you

Comment: Try printing the value of `INT_MAX` - this should give you a clue.

Comment: Where is your code? The memory allocation does not produce any output on its own.

Comment: Where are these numbers coming from?

Comment: Did you use `printf %d` to print an `unsigned int`?

Comment: so if I understand correctly 2147483647 is the limit for unsigned int?

Comment: @ikegami yes,this is wrong?

Comment: `%d` expects a `signed int`

Comment: For `unsigned int` you need `%u`.

Comment: ooo I forgot about it
,now it works great,thanks

Comment: No, the upper limit for `unsigned int` is 4,294,967,295 when it occupies 4 Byte (as on most modern systems) --- 2,147,483,647 for `signed int` when it occupies 4 byte which corresponds to `%d`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get `2147483648` you should use `unsigned int` for both **storing** and **calculating**.

Consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned int n = 31;
    unsigned int *arr = (unsigned int*)malloc((n+1) * sizeof(unsigned int));

    int i;

    for(i=0; i<=n; i++) {
        *(arr+i) = (1<<i);
    }
    for(i=0; i<=n; i++) {
        printf("%u\n", *(arr+i));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This code produces 2147483648 at the end since it uses `unsigned int` for calculation.

Also, make sure you use `%u` as format specifier for output

Comment: Please don't post C++ code in an answer to a C question.

Comment: `%lu` is for `long unsigned int`. `%u` should be used for `unsigned int`. Fixed.

Comment: `(1<<31)` is _undefined behavior_ : shifting in the sign bit.  Recommend using `unsigned` math with `1u << i`.